# How to test ListView items from server using Robolectric 3.0

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I am using Robolectric to test my Application. In my app I want to check the listview is there any items in that view. And test the onClickItem from the listview. The listview items is dynamic from server. Every time the activity is started it will request from server. But, Robolectric didn't wait the response, so the adapter on the listview still Null.

```
@RunWith(CustomRobolectricRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, emulateSdk = 19)
public class HomeScreenTest {

    private HomeActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(HomeActivity.class);
        FakeHttp.getFakeHttpLayer().interceptHttpRequests(true);
        FakeHttp.setDefaultHttpResponse(200, "OK");
        FakeHttpLayer fakeHttpLayer = FakeHttp.getFakeHttpLayer();
        assertFalse(fakeHttpLayer.hasPendingResponses());
        assertFalse(fakeHttpLayer.hasRequestInfos());
        assertFalse(fakeHttpLayer.hasResponseRules());
    }

    @Test
    public void selectItemCategoryMenuShouldStartSearchResultActivity() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        ListView leftDrawer = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        assertThat(leftDrawer).isNotNull();
        leftDrawer.performItemClick(leftDrawer.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null), 0, leftDrawer.getAdapter().getItemId(0));

        Intent intent = shadowOf(activity).peekNextStartedActivity();
        ShadowIntent shadowIntent = shadowOf(intent);
        assertEquals(SearchResultActivity.class.getName(), shadowIntent.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

This is the error from the Robolectric test.

```
Unexpected HTTP call GET http://example.com/api/app/getWallpaper.php HTTP/1.1

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.l23rf.android.stockphoto.HomeScreenTest.selectItemCategoryMenuShouldStartSearchResultActivity(HomeScreenTest.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:235)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:168)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

How to put the Robolectric code to wait the response from server. So the listview adapter is not null anymore, and can test the listview.

Comment: It would be nice to see where exactly line 71 is in your test

Comment: @ihsanhf You are sure that robolectric don't wait? Because robolectric is designed to execute all asynctask synchron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought you were missplacing the initialization.
First you have to set `getFakeHttpLayer().interceptHttpRequests(false)`. Then it should be like this :

```
@Before
public void setUp() {

    FakeHttp.getFakeHttpLayer().interceptHttpRequests(false);
    FakeHttp.setDefaultHttpResponse(200, "OK");
    FakeHttpLayer fakeHttpLayer = FakeHttp.getFakeHttpLayer();
    activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(HomeActivity.class);
    assertFalse(fakeHttpLayer.hasPendingResponses());
    assertFalse(fakeHttpLayer.hasRequestInfos());
    assertFalse(fakeHttpLayer.hasResponseRules());
}
```

Just tell me once you've done to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing a wrong things in your test and code:

- there should not be any assertions in initialization method (`@Before`)
- UI should not call any networking at all, especially on UI thread

About point #1, please read junit [FAQ](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#tests_16). For the point #2 I would advise you to read [this article](https://medium.com/@artem_zin/m-model-from-mvc-mvp-in-android-flow-and-mortar-bd1e50c45395) and use dependency injection to remove network dependency in your UI code.